# NixOS home-manager ssh config permissions

Tags: bash, ssh, nixos

Having a weird issue with ssh config using the [hyper](https://hyper.is/) terminal

Using home-manager I set up matchBlocks

```
home-manager.users.me = { pkgs, ... }: {
  programs.ssh.enable = true;
  programs.ssh.matchBlocks = {
    fooServer = {
    port = 1022;
    hostname =  "example.com";
    user = "me";
  };
};
```

The hyper terminal-emulator is working fine but I'm getting this error when using ssh

`Bad owner or permissions on /home/me/.ssh/config`

I think the permissions on .ssh/config should be 600:

```
drwx------  2 me users 4096 Aug 22 11:58 .
drwx------ 23 me users 4096 Aug 22 11:58 ..
lrwxrwxrwx  1 me users   74 Aug 22 11:58 config -> /nix/store/jn8hzb72d0bjh4894k7h1ys819z96qpl-home-manager-files/.ssh/config
-rw-------  1 me users 3243 Jul 18 13:59 id_rsa
-rw-r--r--  1 me users  749 Jul 18 13:59 id_rsa.pub
-rw-------  1 me users 2234 Aug 13 20:35 known_hosts
```

But this file is automatically generated. Is there a way to change it with home-manager?

I also find it strange that if I use gnome-shell or vscode terminal ssh with config works fine. They all agree on these:

```
[me@computer:~]$ echo $USER
me

[me@computer:~]$ echo $SHELL
/run/current-system/sw/bin/bash

[me@computer:~]$ which ssh
/run/current-system/sw/bin/ssh
```

ssh will work in hyper if I disable config:

```
ssh me@example.com -F none
```

Comment: [so] is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Unix and its utilities. [unix.se] or [su] would be better places for questions like this.

Comment: Is hyper installed with Home Manager?

Answer (score 1):

I just had the same issue and I ended up solving it in the following way:

```
{ ".ssh/config_source" = {
    source = ../shared/config/ssh/config-cmt;
    onChange = ''cat ~/.ssh/config_source > ~/.ssh/config && chmod 600 ~/.ssh/config'';
 };  }
```

**Explanation:**
It as the files managed by home-manager are symlinked in, changing permissions of the symlink doesn't seem to be supported. However, home-manager provides the `onChange` option where you can add in your own shell script. I have home-manager maintain the symlink to the file `~/.ssh/config_source` and then have the `onChange` script copy that to the final target `~/.ssh/config` and set the permissions accordingly.

I realize that this isn't as pure as one would like, but it serves as a workaround.